# Newcomer with AppGyver problems--Steroid and Composer

Tags: node.js, git, composer-php, steroids

**Ok so I've been taking some courses on codecademy on coding and programming and wanted to start a project to test out some of what I've learned. I want to build a Instant Messenger Chat app for phones and after much research I've decided to use AppGyver to build my mobile app.

On the forum I asked what to use and someone informed me that Composer is pretty easy because of the drag option and other stuff but that started frustrating me, there are no good tutorials that show me what everything does on there, esp for what I wanted my app to look like (plus I don't have an Apple smartphone or anything like that so that scanner thing was unnecessary) so since I am familiar with HTML from codecademy I decided to try my luck with that, there are more tuts on that (video of course) and I'm having issues. I went through the steps on the website and everytime I got to the step that asks for me to post this in Node.js

-- npm install steroids -g --

I get a message that keeps saying the same thing--that Python is installed just fine but the error is command 'git' not found. What did I do wrong?

Also I can't seem to locate a repository for Git GUI, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do there either. Could I get some help as to what my problem is? Thank You in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've used the [install wizard](https://academy.appgyver.com/installwizard) on the site? It has comprehensive instructions for installing git, which is required for the `npm install` to work. If you are using Windows, remember to check the "use Git from Windows Command Prompt" checkbox when running the Git installer, after which restart your terminal window and continue with the guide. For further assistance, you should turn to the [AppGyver forums](https://forums.appgyver.com).